# how optimize prestashop category get product for random

Tags: mysql, optimization, random, prestashop

this is prestashop 1.7 version category get product query. if use random, it is very slow, how optimize it?

```
SELECT
    cp.id_category,
    p.*,
    product_shop.*,
    stock.out_of_stock,
    IFNULL( stock.quantity, 0 ) AS quantity,
    IFNULL( product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute, 0 ) AS id_product_attribute,
    product_attribute_shop.minimal_quantity AS product_attribute_minimal_quantity,
    pl.`description`,
    pl.`description_short`,
    pl.`available_now`,
    pl.`available_later`,
    pl.`link_rewrite`,
    pl.`meta_description`,
    pl.`meta_keywords`,
    pl.`meta_title`,
    pl.`name`,
    image_shop.`id_image` id_image,
    il.`legend` AS legend,
    m.`name` AS manufacturer_name,
    cl.`name` AS category_default,
    DATEDIFF(
        product_shop.`date_add`,
    DATE_SUB( "2019-11-30 00:00:00", INTERVAL 7 DAY )) > 0 AS new,
    product_shop.price AS orderprice 
FROM
    `ps_category_product` cp
    LEFT JOIN `ps_product` p ON p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product`
    INNER JOIN ps_product_shop product_shop ON ( product_shop.id_product = p.id_product AND product_shop.id_shop = 1 )
    LEFT JOIN `ps_product_attribute_shop` product_attribute_shop ON ( p.`id_product` = product_attribute_shop.`id_product` AND product_attribute_shop.`default_on` = 1 AND product_attribute_shop.id_shop = 1 )
    LEFT JOIN ps_stock_available stock ON ( stock.id_product = `p`.id_product AND stock.id_product_attribute = 0 AND stock.id_shop = 1 AND stock.id_shop_group = 0 )
    LEFT JOIN `ps_category_lang` cl ON ( product_shop.`id_category_default` = cl.`id_category` AND cl.`id_lang` = 11 AND cl.id_shop = 1 )
    LEFT JOIN `ps_product_lang` pl ON ( p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product` AND pl.`id_lang` = 11 AND pl.id_shop = 1 )
    LEFT JOIN `ps_image_shop` image_shop ON ( image_shop.`id_product` = p.`id_product` AND image_shop.cover = 1 AND image_shop.id_shop = 1 )
    LEFT JOIN `ps_image_lang` il ON ( image_shop.`id_image` = il.`id_image` AND il.`id_lang` = 11 )
    LEFT JOIN `ps_manufacturer` m ON m.`id_manufacturer` = p.`id_manufacturer` 
WHERE
    product_shop.`id_shop` = 1 
    AND cp.`id_category` = 12 
    AND product_shop.`active` = 1 
    AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ( "both", "catalog" ) 
ORDER BY
    RAND() 
    LIMIT 50
```

Comment: How much is "very slow"? Do you have many records if you not set the limit?

Comment: 65173 rows for ps_product,414 rows for category_product, 65162 rows for ps_product_shop.      query about 0.18-0.24 sec

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  Meanwhile, ...

Let's start by **optimizing the joins**.

```
    LEFT JOIN  `ps_product_lang` pl  ON ( p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
              AND  pl.`id_lang` = 11
              AND  pl.id_shop = 1   )
```

That needs `INDEX(id_product, id_lang, id_shop)` (The columns may be in any order.)

**Don't use `LEFT`** unless you really need to fetch a row from the righthand table as NULLs when it does not exist.  In particular,

```
LEFT JOIN  `ps_product` p
```

is probably getting in the way of optimization.

```
    WHERE  product_shop.`id_shop` = 1
      AND  product_shop.`active` = 1
      AND  product_shop.`visibility` IN ( "both", "catalog" )
```

would probably benefit from these **indexes**

```
INDEX(id_shop, active, visibility, id_product)
INDEX(id_product, id_shop, active, visibility)
```

`product_category` needs

```
INDEX(id_category, id_product)   -- in this order.
```

In general **many-to-many mapping tables** need to follow the tips here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

The query has the **"explode-implode" syndrome**.  This is where it first does a `JOINs`, collecting a lot of data, then throws away much of it due, in your case, to the `LIMIT 10`.  It can probably be cured by turning the query inside-out.  The general ID is to start with a derived table that gets the 10 rows desired, *then* reaches into the other table for the rest of the desired columns.  This "reaching" need happen only 10 times, not however many the `JOINs` currently require.

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT <<primary key columns from cp, p, and product_shop>>
               FROM cp
               JOIN p  ON ...
               JOIN product_shop  ON ...
               ORDER BY RAND()
               LIMIT 10 ) AS x
    JOIN  <<p, product_shop ON their PKs>>   -- to get p.*, product_shop.*>>
    [LEFT] JOIN  << each of the other tables>>  -- to get the other tables
```

You should start by testing the subquery (a "derived" table) to verify that it is noticeably faster than the original query.